# Is this use of condition variable safe (taken from cppreference.com)

Tags: c++, condition-variable

Is this code taken from [Example of Producer/Consumer with condition variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) safe? Me and a co-worker had a disagreement whether the omission of std::unique_lock lock(m) in close() is safe. The line `done = true;` is set without a lock. Can the notification get to the other thread without the data being synchonized?

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <chrono>

class condvarQueue
{
    std::queue<int> produced_nums;
    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable cond_var;
    bool done = false;
    bool notified = false;
public:
    void push(int i)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
        produced_nums.push(i);
        notified = true;
        cond_var.notify_one();
    }

    template<typename Consumer>
    void consume(Consumer consumer)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
        while (!done) {
            while (!notified) {  // loop to avoid spurious wakeups
                cond_var.wait(lock);
            }   
            while (!produced_nums.empty()) {
                consumer(produced_nums.front());
                produced_nums.pop();
            }   
            notified = false;
        }   
    }

    void close()
    {
        done = true;
        notified = true;
        cond_var.notify_one();
    }
};

int main()
{
    condvarQueue queue;

    std::thread producer([&]() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            std::cout << "producing " << i << '\n';
            queue.push(i);
        }   
        queue.close();
    }); 

    std::thread consumer([&]() {
         queue.consume([](int input){
             std::cout << "consuming " << input << '\n';
         });
    }); 

    producer.join();
    consumer.join();
}
```

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't guarantee that `bool` is atomic, but in practice it is [citation needed]. This is the type of thing I'd change to a `std::atomic<bool>` for that one embedded system 15 years from now that uses a 64-bit alternating 1/0 pattern for `bool`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one explicitly says that the lock is not required. Personally, I always put it, just to me safe.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Does not the use of the condition variable introduce a barrier that forces syntonization?

Comment: @MartinYork I didn't put enough disclaimers in my first comment. Let me do that here: I'm a C++ novice and very inexperienced with concurrency in general. To be clear: I dunno!

Comment: I have now updated the example at cppreference.com with the accepted answer. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`close` requires locked ownership of `m` while setting `done` and `notified`.  And it isn't about an ancient architecture, it is about modern cached architectures.  Without the locked ownership of `m`, there's no guarantee that the updated values of `done` and `notified` are flushed beyond `close`'s cache line so that they can be read by `consume`.

Whether or not `m` is locked during `cond_var.notify_one()` is not as important.  Both are correct and I've seen articles arguing that one or the other is the most performant.

In summary, either of these are correct:

```
void close()
{
    std::lock_guard lock{m};
    done = true;
    notified = true;
    cond_var.notify_one();
}
```

or:

```
void close()
{
    {
        std::lock_guard lock{m};
        done = true;
        notified = true;
    }
    cond_var.notify_one();
}
```

Note, I'm assuming C++17 with the lack of `<std::mutex>` on `lock_guard`.  I could have also used `unique_lock` instead of `lock_guard` here, but `lock_guard` is the simplest tool for this job.